# Understanding scriptreplay timing file

Tags: scripting, bsd, recording, typescript

I am trying to understand the timing files produced by the `script` command (which are supposed to be read by `scriptreplay` while running typescript files). The timing file is always made of two columns, I guess the first one represents the delay before each chunk of the typescript file is printed. However, I have difficulty understanding the second column. Does it represent the size of each chunk? Or is it just an integer representing the ascii code of the last character in that chunk? Or is it something totally different?

Well, I am guessing since I couldn't find any specification about the timing file format online. I tried reading the implementation of `script` and `scriptreplay` to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual page for [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) gives the answer:

> **`-t`**, **`--timing`**[=file]
>   Output timing data to standard error, or to file when given.
>   This data contains **two** fields, separated by a space.  The
>   **first** field indicates how much time elapsed since the previous
>   output.  The **second** field indicates how many characters were
>   output this time.  This information can be used to replay
>   typescripts with realistic typing and output delays.

So "size of each chunk" is correct.

Comment: I definitely should have checked out the manual first. Thanks.

Comment: I recalled that it was there, but surprised that it was not in `scriptreplay`...

Comment: Something not explicitly mentioned is that is that scriptreplay ignores the first line of the script file which reads "Script started on..." (at least in my locale). I wrote a simple program to do some processing on scripts and timing files and was confused as to why the data didn't seem to line up with times until I noticed this.